# Shortest directed path connecting given subset of vertices

Tags: graphs, terminology, shortest-path, weighted-graphs

Given

- weighted directed graph $G = (V,E,w)$, where $w : E \to \mathbb R^+$
- source vertex $v \in V$
- vertex subset $U \subset V$

how to find a shortest directed path from $v$ containing all vertices from $U$? Note that such path may contain vertices that are not in $U$.

1. Does such problem have a name?
2. How to find a solution?

Comment: See this question: [Find the shortest path in a graph which visits certain nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222413/find-the-shortest-path-in-a-graph-which-visits-certain-nodes)

Comment: Try the [Held-Karp algorithm](https://www.google.com/search?q=Held-karp+algorithm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is NP-complete, by reduction from Hamiltonian path. Given an instance $G=(V,E)$ of Hamiltonian path, add a new vertex $s$ connected to all original vertices; this edges are directed *from* $s$, and all the original graph edges are bidirectional. Give all edges unit weight. There is a path from $s$ visiting all of $V$ of weight $|V|$ if and only if $G$ has a Hamiltonian path.

Comment: The question asks not for complexity of the problem, but for known names.

Comment: @Raphael I'm actually interested both in an algorithm and in the name. I made it more clear in the question.